# Individual columns in databricks/spark-sql from JSON objects

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using databricks platform to work with JSON dataset. Each JSON looks like this:

```
{
"I": {
    "Country_code": 123,
    "City_code": 278,
    "Parameters": {
        "Param1": 120,
        "Param2": 200,
        "Param3": 100
    }
},
"II": {
    "Country_code": 567,
    "City_code": 883,
    "Parameters": {
        "Param1": 223,
        "Param2": 557,
        "Param3": 662
    }
}
```

}

What I want to achieve is a dataframe/table that will look like this

| Number | Country_code | City_code | Param1 | Param2 | Param3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | 123 | 278 | 120 | 200 | 100 |
| II | 278 | 883 | 223 | 557 | 662 |

As you can see I need to make outer objects ("I","II") as rows of table and internal objects (Country_code, City_code and objects of "Parameters") as columns.

I was able to do part of it manually for first row (I) by:

```
df.select("I.Country_code", "I.City_code", "I.Parameters.Param1", "I.Parameters.Param2", "I.Parameters.Param3")
```

Problems that I'm facing:

1. I don't know how to put outer objects (I, II) as rows in table
2. I don't know which function to use to automatically map each Param1, Param2... ParamX to be individual column. There might be up to 100 Params so my previous manual approach is not optimal.